# How to view how a link was opened in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, website

A suspicious link was opened in my Chrome browser and it began downloading files automatically. I'm pretty sure I didn't click anything, so is there a way for me to view how a link was opened in Chrome? (ex. google.com - address bar, example.com - redirected from gmail.com)

Comment: View source code of header and email contents ... file>view header ....

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't saved the link, find it in history. Install uBlock and add (r-lick on uBlock icon, Options, My filters) the "adequate prefix" (meaning not the whole text but maybe not just the site/domain, depending on what it is, there's a number of examples that show all kinds of variations). Usually I add just the bare domain (without www. like [stupiddope.com]).

Once it's there, the next time it tries uBlock is going to stop it and depending on how aggressive it is, you may also see which page tried or a message in dev console (blocked by client or blocked by extension). Also uBlock has a menu option "requests blocked" which is a kind of mini log.